# Export model to show it in web-browser

Tags: modeling, export, three.js, webgl

I'm looking for a way of exporting my Blender model in web-browser. I noticed this [very cool video with model in browser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYZ976CMsus) and I want to make the same site. The project was done by three.js but I'm very novice in programming . Is there are more efficient ways or another alternatives in exporting Blender model to the web-browser?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: See www.sketchfab.com ... useful for sharing 3D models -- including native Blender animations -- online. You can link to sketchfab model display pages, and/or embed them in your own website...

Answer (score 4):

Blend4Web can do most of the work for you. It exports Blender models correctly and also sets up the WebGL page. It's free and open source.

https://www.blend4web.com/en/

Comment: It is open core, and only free for personal use. Currently, a "pro" license is $990 US.

Answer (score 0):

[Khronos group](https://www.khronos.org/) (those who defined OpenGL) have now defined the [GL Transmission format](https://www.khronos.org/gltf/), which is the main supported export import format for multiple tools and web apis such as [three.js](https://threejs.org/) which recommends its usage.

With a glTF, you can embed your 3d scene in a web page with one line of code (plus one to reference the library). see [see this babylon.js viewer]

As I had the same question and had to investigate this, I created here 
[multiple boilerplate examples](https://github.com/HomeSmartMesh/web_three_interface) with three.js . Each has a live demo helping show exports from blender with hints how to make them interactive in the browser such as getting mouse clicks and changing their paramters, colors animation from javascript events.

Github :

https://github.com/HomeSmartMesh/web_three_interface

Live demos on github pages :

https://homesmartmesh.github.io/web_three_interface/

This question was asked in 3 years ago, but still appears in the search so this is sort of an update.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed your 3D models for free in three easy steps using http://p3d.in.
The site that was created by Blender contributors and is free for personal and commercial use.

1. Export your model in gltf, fbx, obj or another supported format
2. Upload the model to p3d.in
3. Embed the model with a [single line of code, or use the URL directly](https://p3d.in/faq/embed)