# is there a way to export 3D model as a 3D rather than 2D render?

Tags: 3d-view

I want to post my 3D models on social media, not as a screenshot but in 3D view. (See [this article](https://developers.facebook.com/products/3d-posts/) for an example.)

Like if someone is opening it then he/she can have a full 3D view of it (mobile/desktop).

How do I output such a 3D image from Blender?

Comment: This is not a question about Blender, rather how to preview online models created with it. Look up Sketchfab or Marmoset Viewer services and their facilities to show data outside of their sites

Comment: It's a poorly worded question, probably because the OP doesn't know what a panoramic render is, but the OP is simply asking how to create a panoramic render.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export model to show it in web-browser](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49882/export-model-to-show-it-in-web-browser)   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178946/exporting-from-blender-to-browser-web-viewer-what-is-the-best-way